# I want to share cart between multiple magento 2.1 website

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento2

We have multiple websites with multi-currency, Different payment methods, shipping methods etc. some products are shared with the different price/Currency on websites.

If a user buys particular product on one site and changes the site product must be present in the cart with the updated price and currency. Is there any module available for this or any customization we can do for this please suggest. Any help is appreciated.